# Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{ie.ensureCleanSession=true}], required capabilities while launching IE

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver, mutablecapabilities

I have updated IE Driver to 3.12.0.0 and it is not working. I get the below error message

**Code:**

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\iedriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

**Error Message from Console**

```
Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{ie.ensureCleanSession=true}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You need to use the method [**`merge()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) method from [**MutableCapabilities**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class to merge the *DesiredCapabilities* type of object into *InternetExplorerOptions* type object and initiate the *WebDriver* and *WebClient* instance by passing the *InternetExplorerOptions* object as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\iedriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
options.merge(cap);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

PS : As a reference you can have a look at the discussions in [**`mutablecapabilities`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutablecapabilities) tag